# ResourceType mismatch in Set-AzDiagnosticSetting

Tags: azure, powershell, diagnostics, azure-log-analytics, azure-diagnostics

I want to update (not create) existing Diagnostic Settings entries for network related resources, they miss retention days variables and workspace assignment, but when I use this command:

```
$WorkspaceId = "..."
$ResourceId = "..."   
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -resourceid $ResourceId -RetentionEnabled $True -RetentionInDays 31 -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId
```

I get this error:

Set-AzDiagnosticSetting : Exception type: ErrorResponseException, Message: Null/Empty, Code: Null, Status code:BadRequest, Reason phrase: Bad Request

When I use alternative way of

```
$get = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -resourceid $ResourceId
Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -InputObject $get -MetricCategory AllMetrics -RetentionEnabled $True -RetentionInDays 31 -WorkspaceId $WorkspaceId
```

I get this error: Set-AzDiagnosticSetting : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.

Can I actually update the entry with Set-AzDiagnosticSetting or only create one? Or I'm stuck with removing all diagnostic settings entires for network objects and assigning them properly again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not pass the fully qualified ID of the Workspace, you get the below error:

[image]
But if you provide the correct Workspace ID i.e. **fully qualified ID of the workspace** you can get rid of this error.

[image]

And to use the alternative way, use it in this way, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.monitor/set-azdiagnosticsetting?view=azps-3.8.0) (Example 5: Using pipeline).

```
Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId "Resource01" | Set-AzDiagnosticSetting -Enabled $True -Category Category1,Category2
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realized WorkspaceID flag actually requires full resource id.